# Setting/Getting Values in a Repeat Control using Managed Java Bean

Tags: java, xpages

I have a repeat control on my XPage:

```
    <xp:repeat id="DriverRepeat" var="rowData" indexVar="rowIndex" value="#{javascript:requestBean.getDrivers();}">
        <xp:label value="#{javascript:rowData.driverInfo}" />
        <xp:inputText value="#{requestBean.driverChanges}" />
    </xp:repeat>
```

I have a managed bean (requestBean) bound to my XPage. I'm able to read/save other non-repeat control values using `value="#{requestBean.driverChanges}"` and in my Java bean:

`private String driverChanges;`

getter/setters:

```
public void setDriverChanges(String driverChanges) {
    this.driverChanges = driverChanges;
}

public String getDriverChanges() {
    return driverChanges;
}
```

load value:

```
setDriverChanges(doc.getItemValueString("DriverChanges"));
```

save value:

```
doc.replaceItemValue("DriverChanges", driverChanges);
```

But this doesn't work with repeat control fields because they are multi-valued. I tried making `driverChanges` a Vector but I wasn't sure how to structure the inputText field value with the managed bean. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: What does driverChanges contain? Is it a multi-value field for one driver each or one field for all drivers together?

Comment: @KnutHerrmann - I need a text field for each driver to indicate what is changing on that specific driver. So that field is repeated for each driver. This is where I'm unsure how to bind it to my managed bean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your question and your comments you have a requestBean which represents a Request document. This document has two multi value fields

- DriverInfo
- DriverChanges

Each element of multi value list represents a driver. First driver's info is in first element of  DriverInfo and first driver's changes are in first element of DriverChanges and so on.

```
DriverInfo    DriverChanges
driver1       changes1
driver2       changes2
driver3       changes3
```

You'd like to create a repeat control which shows data for each driver in a separate line like this

[image]

Change your requestBean to

```java
public class RequestBean implements Serializable {
    ...

    private Vector<String> driverInfo;
    private Vector<String> driverChanges;

    public Vector<String> getDrivers() throws Exception {
        ...
        setDriverInfo(doc.getItemValue("DriverInfo"));
        setDriverChanges(doc.getItemValue("DriverChanges"));
        return driverInfo;
    }

    public void setDriverInfo(Vector<String> driverInfo) {
        this.driverInfo = driverInfo;
    }

    public Vector<String> getDriverInfo() {
        return driverInfo;
    }

    public void setDriverChanges(Vector<String> driverChanges) {
        this.driverChanges = driverChanges;
    }

    public Vector<String> getDriverChanges() {
        return driverChanges;
    }

    public void save() throws Exception {
        ...
        doc.replaceItemValue("driverInfo", getDriverInfo());
        doc.replaceItemValue("driverChanges", getDriverChanges());
        doc.save();
    }
}
```

and change your repeat control to

```xml
<xp:repeat
    id="DriverRepeat"
    var="rowData"
    indexVar="rowIndex"
    value="#{javascript:requestBean.getDrivers()}">
    <xp:label value="#{rowData}" />
    <xp:inputText value="#{requestBean.driverChanges[rowIndex]}" />
    <br />
</xp:repeat>
```

`requestBean.getDrivers()` returns a Vector of driverInfos. `rawData` holds the driverInfo for current driver inside repeat.
`requestBean.driverChanges[rowIndex]` calls requestBean's method `getDriverChanges()`, returns a Vector of driverChanges and selects only the value for current driver with rowIndex.

Comment: Would you then set: 

`setDriverChanges(doc.getItemValueString("DriverChanges"));`
and
`doc.replaceItemValue("DriverChanges", driverChanges);`

in the Driver class?

Comment: Yes, you would probably use setDriverChanges() in method getDrivers() for every driver document.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused when you say "for every driver document". In my application, I  have a requestBean which contains logic for saving all the data to the main Request document. Are you saying to create separate driver documents now?

Comment: I changed my answer completely after your comments. I hope I understood you right this time :)

Comment: For beauty change value="#{javascript:requestBean.getDrivers()}" to value="#{requestBean.drivers}"